# Google App Engine Help?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

Thanks for taking time to read my question.

I'm trying to embed something like [this](http://www.yvoschaap.com/youtube/) on my website using google app engine. To accomplish this my understanding is I have to upload a .js file. I currently have this code on my page:

```
<script src='/ytembed.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="youtubeDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">ytEmbed.init({'block':'youtubeDiv','type':'search','q':'03728D7DF4BBDC66','results':'50','order':'highest_rating','width': 200, 'height': 200, 'layout': thumbnails});</script><br>
```

It only returns a blank page. I figured it's because i have some sort of failed implementation of the .js file.

This is my app file currently :

```
application: ********* 
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: .*
  script: main.py

- url: \1
  script: ytembed.js
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use the `static_dir` configuration like this:

```
application: ********* 
    version: 1
    runtime: python
    api_version: 1

    handlers:

    - url: /static/
      static_dir: static

    - url: .*
      script: main.py
```

And put the `ytembed.js` in `static/js/ytembed.js` from the root directory of your application, and point to the js file with the url `http://APPHOST/static/js/ytembed.js`.